# Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.The data for table-valued parameter "@dt" doesn't conform to the table type

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

[image]

I am getting error

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.
>   The data for table-valued parameter "@dt" doesn't conform to the table type of the parameter.

I have created a SQL Server table type:

```
CREATE TYPE NACVCC AS TABLE
(
    CurrentNACV decimal(5,3),
    Year1NACV decimal(5,3),
    Year2NACV decimal(5,3),
    Year3NACV decimal(5,3),
    Year4NACV decimal(5,3),
    Year5NACV decimal(5,3),
    NACVText nvarchar(255)
);
GO
```

Stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertNACVCC
    @dt AS dbo.NACVCC READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    TRUNCATE TABLE GPSNACVCC

    INSERT dbo.GPSNACVCC(NACVText, CurrentNACV, Year1, Year2, Year3, Year4, Year5)
       SELECT 
          NACVText, CurrentNACV, 
          Year1NACV, Year2NACV, Year3NACV, Year4NACV ,Year5NACV  
       FROM @dt;
END
GO
```

And from C# I am calling like this :

```
public static void InsertUSNACVCC(DataTable tvp)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
    {
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.InsertNACVCC", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter tvparam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", tvp);
        tvparam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

`Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` returns the error mentioned. I have matched the datatype it is `nvarchar(255)` in type and table as well.

Please help

Comment: Have you tried to debug?
Seems like you have some incompatible data (or table structure) in the tvp variable.

Comment: @Zohar: Added TVP Data pic above.Please have a look.

Comment: I'ts been a while since I've done this sort of thing, but I think that the column names in your c# dataTable should be the same as in the sql type. if not the same names then at least the same order. As posted, it seems that the sql engine is selecting the wrong columns from the data it gets.

Comment: Can we see your DataTable configuration?

Answer (score 9):

For anyone else finding this - I had exact same issue, The column names were the same, as were the datatypes, but the order was different - the fix was to ensure the order of columns in the `DataTable` matched the order of columns in the table type.

Comment: This was the issue for me as well. Thanks @Mr. Bownstone I lost 3 days before I encountered your answer.